# Best way to filter DBpedia results and return a specific results using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, virtuoso

I have a little problem...

From a list on wikipedia Page Ids, i want to return:

- pageid
- Abstract ( English)
- Thumbnail
- type

***Only for company OR university page***

I have this simple SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
select ?pageid ?abstract ?thumbnail  ?company ?type 
where {
    ?resource dbpedia-owl:wikiPageID ?pageid;
    dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract 
. OPTIONAL { 
    ?resource dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail
     } 
 . OPTIONAL { 
    ?resource  dbpedia-owl:type ?type
    } 
. OPTIONAL { 
    ?resource ?company dbpedia-owl:Company 
    }

FILTER( 
?pageid = 14617 || ?pageid = 26989 || ?pageid = 31776 || 
?pageid = 256913 || ?pageid = 342924 || ?pageid = 1785141 || 
?pageid = 3057187 || ?pageid = 7529378 || ?pageid = 18978754 
)
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en"))
}
```

I have this result: [SPARQL Result](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia2%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+skos%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbpedia-owl%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0Aselect+%3Fpageid+%3Fabstract+%3Fthumbnail++%3Fcompany+%3Ftype+where+%7B%0D%0A%3Fresource+dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageID+%3Fpageid%3B%0D%0Adbpedia-owl%3Aabstract+%3Fabstract+.+OPTIONAL+%7B+%0D%0A%3Fresource+dbpedia-owl%3Athumbnail+%3Fthumbnail%0D%0A+%7D+%0D%0A+.+OPTIONAL+%7B+%0D%0A%3Fresource++dbpedia-owl%3Atype+%3Ftype%0D%0A%0D%0A+%7D+%0D%0A.+OPTIONAL+%7B+%0D%0A%3Fresource+%3Fcompany+dbpedia-owl%3ACompany+%0D%0A%0D%0A+%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AFILTER%28+%3Fpageid+%3D+14617+%7C%7C+%3Fpageid+%3D+26989+%7C%7C+%3Fpageid+%3D+31776+%7C%7C+%3Fpageid+%3D+256913+%7C%7C+%3Fpageid+%3D+342924+%7C%7C+%3Fpageid+%3D+1785141+%7C%7C+%3Fpageid+%3D+3057187+%7C%7C+%3Fpageid+%3D+7529378+%7C%7C+%3Fpageid+%3D+18978754+%29%0D%0A+filter%28langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&stylesheet=xml-to-html.xsl)

I managed to return the data that I wanted except that I cannot filter only that companies and universities.

is there any idea on how to remove pages that are not companies or universities in the dbpedia query results?

Comment: what is the purpose of this: `OPTIONAL { 
    ?resource ?company dbpedia-owl:Company 
    }` ?

Comment: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?pageid ?abstract ?thumbnail ?type where {
VALUES ?type {dbo:Company dbo:University}
VALUES ?pageid {14617 26989 31776 256913 342924 1785141 3057187 7529378 18978754 }
?resource dbo:wikiPageID ?pageid;
rdf:type ?type;
dbo:abstract ?abstract . 
OPTIONAL { ?resource dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail} 
FILTER(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en"))
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AKSW has provided a query that does what you want, but I think it would be better with some more detailed explanation of why.  So, here is that query, with a bunch of whitespace and some inline comments to help clarify --

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT ?pageid ?abstract ?thumbnail ?type 
WHERE
  { 

  # the next couple lines limit rdf:type values
    VALUES ?type
           { dbo:Company dbo:University } 

  # the next few lines limit dbo:wikiPageID values
    VALUES ?pageid 
           {   14617     26989      31776
              256913    342924    1785141
             3057187   7529378   18978754 } 

  # the next few lines get values for the 3 predicates 
  # you required for each subject
               ?resource  dbo:wikiPageID  ?pageid ; 
                          rdf:type        ?type ; 
                          dbo:abstract    ?abstract . 

  # the next line gets thumbnails, if they exist
    OPTIONAL { ?resource  dbo:thumbnail   ?thumbnail } 

  # the next line limits the solutions you receive to those 
  # with an abstract langtagged as "en"
    FILTER ( langMatches ( lang ( ?abstract ), "en" ) ) 

  }
```